# qpainterpath.addtext ignores qfont weight

Tags: fonts, qt4, qpainter

Using Qt 4.7.0, we need some text to display part way between normal and bold.  Here's what we're doing:

In the `Paint` method of our subclass of `QGraphicsObject`, we have a `QFont` that we call `setWeight(58)` on.  We create a `QPainterPath` and call its `addText` method, passing in our `QFont`.

We then use the `QPainter` parameter to call `drawPath`, passing in our `QPainterPath`.

What we've found is changes in fontweight from 50 to 62 make no difference in how it is painted.  With a fontweight of 63 to 75, the font is painted bold.

How can we get the fontWeight to work as we expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfont.html#setWeight):

> Sets the weight the font to weight,
>   which should be a value from the
>   QFont::Weight enumeration.

The [W3C page on CSS font boldness](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness) has a good explanation of how CSS handles it; the Qt documentation says it is doing something similar. Basically, it applies some heuristic to try to map your weight value to the appropriate version of the font (regular, bold, heavy, etc.)

It may be possible (perhaps outlining a `QPainterPath`?) to create slightly-thicker-than-normal glyphs of a certain font, but the results are almost certainly going to be disappointing. Font designers put a lot of effort into making fonts look good at certain weights. When you depart from that (say, by outlining each glyph), all that design optimization is lost.